# How I remove grub text in ubuntu3 version?

Tags: grub2

How I remove GRUB text

> "**Use the up or down arrow keys to select which entry is highlighted. Press enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit the commands before booting, or 'c' for a command-line.** "

in Ubuntu3 version?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved this question, but even though it's a bit late, I have been playing with [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) which allows you to edit most parts of the Grub system.

Answer (score 0):

Set the normal text color to match the background color. Use Grub Customizer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on why the menu is coming up, do you have any other OS's installed on any HDD's?

I would suggest installing Grub Customizer with the following commands in the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Once this is installed, run it (should show in the dash) and go to the "general settings" tab. In here there is a section called "visibility". See if "show menu" or "look for other operating systems" is ticked and untick them, choose save and then reboot and see if it is fixed.

It may be coming up because Ubuntu is finding an error somewhere and suspects you may want to go into recovery mode. In this case you would need to work out what the error is and solve it.